# How to override methods with an interface in java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, overloading

I have an interface I, two classes A & B that implement it and a list with generic type the interface I, so it can contain both objects of type A & B.

```
class A implements I
class B implements I
List<I> myList
```

I would like to write (in a separate class) two methods process( A a ) and process( B b ) so I can loop through the list and for each element call process( i ) and java will automatically (unbox?) the object and invoke the correct method.

```
class D{
    processList(){
        for( I i : myList ){
            process( i ); // invoke either process(A) or process(B) based on instanceof
        }
    }
    public void process(A a){...}
    public void process(B b){...}
}
```

I know I can do this by invoking 'instanceof' on each element in the list and then if-else to call the different methods, but there must be a better way.

In a MVC scenario, classes A and B are in the Model, while class D is in the Controller, thus the need for separation.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you show a bit more example code?  I'm having a hard time reading between the few lines you show.

Comment: EDIT: Where are the process methods?  You show them outside of class D.

Comment: Sorry about that, the process methods are inside class D.

Comment: use a wrapper method in which you handle the if-else with instanceof

Comment: That's a terrible solution, but the only one I see available.  The OP would be much better to take the answer by Eliott below.

Answer (score 6):

> there must be a better way.

There is. Add the method process() to the interface `I`. Then you can call `process` on the items while you iterate the `List<I>` -

```
List<I> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
// populate list with A and B instances, then
for (I i : list) {
  i.process();
}
```

Obviously `A` and `B` must then provide concrete implementations of `process()`.

Comment: Thanks but that will not work for me, the process method needs to be in a separate class that handles the user interface.

Comment: If this isn't an option, then the next-best alternative may be to use the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: @max I think programming to the interface is the correct solution. You can invoke the interface method in your seperate class, you'd have to have an instance there somehow to do something with an A or a B.

Comment: It looks like you could do this with the Visitor Pattern and double dispatch, but the Visitor Pattern requires that you add the process methods to the base class (here, to the interface).  OP says he can't.

Comment: A and B are in the model, D is in the controller (more like the view actually) so the 'process' method would have to include UI specific code.

Comment: And what is I?  Why can't you modify that interface with a process() method?  Can you insert another base class, X, which implements I and and have your A and B classes extend X?

Comment: I agree with @markspace. If you're restricting yourself because of perceived MVC requirements, then you'd be "penny wise but pound foolish".